# I test pyttsx3 and all is allways the same, robotic voice , i cannot change this voice

Tags: ubuntu, xfce, pyttsx3

```
enter code here
```

import pyttsx3
import os
texte = input("le texte à exprimer ? : ")

tts = pyttsx3.init()

tts.say(texte)

voices = tts.getProperty('voices')

tts.setProperty("voice", voices[1].id)

tts.runAndWait()

i tried to change setProperty("voice",voices[0].id) but nothing change, impossible to have a beautifull woman voice
I am on Xubuntu 20.04 LTS , i put ffmpeg and other lib
When i look a tuto on Youtube with exactly the same code, it is ok but with windows
Can you help me please
Pierre

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the script run in Windows but not in Xubuntu, it is a robotic voice but i want the voice of a women and nice prononciation, sorry i speak french

Comment: same problem here. A robotic voice on ubuntu 20.04